# angularjs ui bootstrap Typeahead not working

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-bootstrap

I am using angular 1.5 version and angularjs ui bootstrap 1.3.3 , typeahead is not working as expected. On typing in the textbox the appropriate autocomplete options are not getting displayed. I am new to angularjs can anyone please help.
Is there anything wrong in the code. Also is there any way in which I can create the autocomplete textbox using only angularjs without bootstrap.

Below is the code for the same

```
    <script type="text/javascript" src="/docs/js/angular.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular-ui-bootstrap/1.3.3/ui-bootstrap-tpls.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="/docs/js/controller/invoiceApprController.js"></script>
<div id="ng-app" ng-app="TabsApp">
    <input type="text" ng-model="name" ng-controller="DController" typeahead="dealVal.Id as dealVal.name for dealVal in deals| filter:name">
</div>
```

Below is the code for the controller in the js file included

```
var angularModule= angular.module('TabsApp', ['ui.bootstrap']);
angularModule.controller('DController',['$scope', '$http', function($scope,$http){
        $http
        .get('/url').success(function(data, status) {
            $scope.deals = data.items;
        })
        .error(function(data, status) {
                   alert(status);
        });
        }]);
```

Comment: take a look at here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18460374/angularjs-autocomplete-from-http